# How to configure Express app with Vue Router?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building an Express based app that works as follows:

- '/' static main site served by Express with pug templating engine
- '/admin' admin panel handled by VueJS with Vue Router in history mode

At the moment if I go to *'/admin/about'* it works fine, but when I refresh the page it throws the 404 error. How do I configure the server to handle all admin routes ('/admin/xxx') with Vue Router but all main site routes with Express (as it currently does)?

I've tried using **connect-history-api-fallback** middleware but with no success.

**app.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const publicRoutes = require('./routes/index');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', 'views');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

app.use(publicRoutes);

app.use(history());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).render('404', {
        pageTitle: 'Page Not Found'
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('home/index', {
        pageTitle: 'Lorem Ipsum',
        path: '/'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/admin.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('admin/index', {
        pageTitle: 'Admin Panel',
        path: '/'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current configuration handles just root path `/` for the admin SPA(so you get 404 on all admin pages except the root if you tries to refresh page). You can allow all admin urls to be "processed" by Vue app on client(even 404 errors) with `/*` instead of `/` in your route.

But there will be a problem with http status codes because (as you probably guessed) server will always return 200 for every route... but I think most of developers are ok with this and just showing some 404-page-component for user if there is no component matched the url.

If you want to see correct http codes in your browser for web consistency, debugging, project requirements or something - without SSR, you will have to repeat your client routes in back-end I think.